# Using sed to remove everything after a [[:space:]]

Tags: sed, grep

How can I remove everything after a whitespace? I can do it if I specify the colon ':' rather than [[:space:]].

```
$ cat t.sh
echo "DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" | \
    sed -r -e 's#.*\(DW_Prod.*\)[[:space:]].*#\\1#'

$ ./t.sh
DW_Prod\Facets\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql
```

Comment: Side note: you don't need to escape the linebreak after a pipe.

Comment: Rid the sed flags and the double escape on the hold pattern: `echo "DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" |     sed 's#.*\(DW_Prod.*\)[[:space:]].*#\1#'`

Comment: Great answers from all. I marked the first chronologically as the answer. Many thanks.

Comment: You might want to THINK about the answers you got rather than just choosing the first one that produces the output you expect from a given sample input set. There are significant differences between the answers. If you can't tell by reading the answers that they are different then take a look at the upvote counts from others who can tell. If it's not obvious to you what the differences are then you should ask questions. I do NOT want you to suddenly accept my answer just because I posted this comment, I'm just advising you actually THINK about any solutions rather than just accepting the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything after the whitespace, that would be:

```
echo "DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" | sed -r 's/([[:space:]]+).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

You are enabling ERE metachars with `-r` and then disabling the ERE capture groups `(...)` by escaping the delimiters `\(...\)` and disabling the backreference `\1` by escaping the backslash `\\1`. Try this:

```
$ echo "DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" | \
    sed -r -e 's#.*(DW_Prod.*)[[:space:]].*#\1#'
DW_Prod\Facets\UNRCH_MBRS:
```

All you really need though is:

```
$ echo "DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" |
    sed 's#[[:space:]].*##'
DW_Prod\Facets\UNRCH_MBRS:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep -o (exact match) and a regex of not a space:
`grep -o '^[^ ]*' <<< "DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql"`