# How to specify an alternating group to a sed regex

Tags: regex, sed

This is an additional part of [Using sed to remove everything after a [[:space:]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520786/using-sed-to-remove-everything-after-a-space). I know StackOverflow wants new questions rather than add-ons to existing questions.

I want to remove everything after a non-path character from the string that contains `DW_Prod`. For now, I am saying that a colon and a space are the end of the string. Yes, I know that paths may contain spaces. These are not supposed to. If it is missed, that's ok for this documentation work.

```
$ echo "blah DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" |
    sed 's#.*\(DW_Prod.*\)\(:\|[[:space:]]\).*#\1#'
DW_Prod\Facets\UNRCH_MBRS:
```

How does regex know the difference between a result group specified by `()` and an alternating group specified by `(a|b|c)`?

Comment: Groups are numbered from left to right. `(a|b|c)` is not an "alternating group", it's a group that contains an alternation, that's all. As an aside, not all sed implementations support the alternation in BRE.

Comment: What's your expected output for given input in question?

Comment: You have fundamental misunderstandings of regexp concepts and syntax. The question you're asking now is meaningless (a capture group is a capture group no matter what regexp it contains) and you would not write `\(:\|[[:space:]]\)` to do what you want but instead just `[:[:space:]]` with no capture group and no `|`, just a bracket expression containing a character and a character class. Go read a regexp tutorial to learn the basics and then come back with questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove everything after ... DW_Prod ... I am saying that a colon and a space are the end of the string.

```
$ echo "blah DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" | \
  sed -n -e 's#^.*\(DW_Prod.*[:[:space:]]\).*$#\1#p'
DW_Prod\Facets\UNRCH_MBRS:
```

Or

```
$ echo "blah DW_Prod\\Facets\\UNRCH_MBRS: UNRCH_Members.sql" | \
  sed -n -e 's#^.*\(DW_Prod[^:[:space:]]*[:[:space:]]\).*$#\1#p'
DW_Prod\Facets\UNRCH_MBRS:
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer. Ultimately, the answer for this situation was `sed -r -e 's#^.*(DW_Prod[^:[:space:]]*).*#\1#I'`